# How to upload a file with Terraform and AWS S3 using Multi Region access point

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I am trying to upload a file to S3 Bucket using multi-region access point and
Terraform. However, Terraform says The S3 arn should have a region but, multi-region
access point does not define any region.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "examplebucket_object" {
  key    = "test.jpg"
  bucket = "arn:aws:s3::111111111111:accesspoint/aaaaaaaaaaaaa.mrap"
  source = "test.jpg"
}

Error: Error uploading object to S3 bucket 
(arn:aws:s3::111111111111:accesspoint/aaaaaaaaaaaaa.mrap): InvalidARNError: invalid 
ARN
caused by: invalid Amazon s3 ARN, region not set, 
arn:aws:s3::111111111111:accesspoint/aaaaaaaaaaaaa.mrap

with aws_s3_bucket_object.examplebucket_object,
on main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "examplebucket_object":
1: resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "examplebucket_object" {
```

I tried the same with aws cli. it worked well.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: What is the resource managing the bucket?

Comment: I have two buckets managed by muti region access point. us-east-1 and us-east-2 arn:aws:s3:::test-us-east-1-1111 and arn:aws:s3:::test-us-east-2-2222 . is that your question?

Comment: Probably its not supported.